# How to show only current section/subsection in beamer ?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer, navigation

I was wondering, if it is possible to **show only the current section** and subsection in the navigation bar ? 
In the default configuration, the navigationbar uses too much space of the slide. With

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
```

the items are squashed together.

Here is a minimal example:

```
% packages
\documentclass[serif,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, epsfig, xspace}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

% template
\usetheme{default}
\useoutertheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 


\begin{document}

 \section{section a}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 1} \end{frame}
 \section{section b}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 2} \end{frame}
 \section{section c}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 3} \end{frame}
 \section{section d}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 4} \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _default configuration_? The `default` theme has no navigation bar at all.

Comment: Nope. Still no navigation bar for me, even with those commands; the problem must be somewhere else. Could you write a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Added a MWE in the description.

Answer (score 11):

You can either use the `infolines` outer theme, or set the `headline` beamer template using `\insertsectionhead` and `\insertsubsectionhead`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsubsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 

\begin{document}

 \section{Test section a}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 1} \end{frame}
 \subsection{Test subsection a1}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 2} \end{frame}
 \subsection{Test subsection a2}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 3} \end{frame}
 \section{Test section b}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 4} \end{frame}
 \subsection{Test subsection b1}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 5} \end{frame}
 \subsection{Test subsection b2}
    \begin{frame} \frametitle{frame 6} \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

The solution is using a different outer-theme

```
\useoutertheme{infolines}
```

Comment: I see. The non- _default_ package causing all this was `beamerthemesplit`, a legacy theme; `\usetheme{Malmoe}` is now the recommended equivalent. By default, `Malmoe`'s navigation bar shows all sections and subsections. You can change this behavior by selecting the `infolines` outer theme, as you and Gonzalo pointed out, or by selecting a different theme, like `CambridgeUS`.

Comment: When I use this command, frametitle (when exists) overlaps the headine. How can we fix it?